# How to change the memory size of an ova appliance before deploying it on VCenter Server?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, virtual-appliances

In this [Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/528245/should-i-lower-memory-config-of-vmware-vcenter-server-appliance) [george](https://serverfault.com/users/172707/george) was asking if it is OK to lower the memory of VMware Virtual Appliance.

What I would like to know is **how to modify memory size in the ova file before the deployment?** because after the deployment in Vcenter Server if I lower the memory size the VM refuses to spawn requiring at Least 8GB of memory.

Comment: Does the VM require 8GB of RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VMware Workstation I've been able to modify the OVA Appliance memory size, here are the steps:

1. Import the ova appliance in VMWare Workstation
2. Modify Virtual Hardware properties in VM settings
3. Export the Modified VM has a OVF Model
4. In VCenter deploy the VM using the OVF model (recall that the OVF is just a descriptor for the VMDK disk image)

I would like also to acknowledge that this is for a prototype deployment.

Answer (score 3):

Without making some configuration changes, vCenter *will* require at least 8 GB of RAM to function properly because of some of the hard-coded values for Java and other dependencies.

For reference, this is a setup with 2 hosts and 22 VMs, using the Web client:

```
esxi-vcenter:~ # free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          8002       7872        130          0        380       3828
-/+ buffers/cache:       3663       4339
Swap:        15366          4      15362
```

Yes, some is cached, but usage does spike depending on activity, so I highly recommend leaving it at 8 GB.